# Unclosed Polygons

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have received a polygon shapefile from contractors. Opening the layer in QGIS, the layer is identified as a polygon. Many of the polygons are not closed (something that happened when downloading from GPS).

Is there a plugin or method to close the polygon? I have searched, but maybe not hard enough.

[image]

**EDIT**

Picture added. The polygon layer Full assessment survey is a polygon layer. I have made the outline thick to show that some objects are not closed.

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: @underdark we need to upvote the OP some so they can actually add the pic :)

Comment: Or, provide the Shapefile?

Comment: Have you looked at the v.clean GRASS tool in QGIS? https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/v.clean.html

Comment: @elrobis - if they provide a link the mods (or other users) can edit it in

Comment: Picture added to show unclosed polygons.

Comment: Did you try the `Polygons to Lines` tool and then running `Lines to polygons` tool after? You can run these from either the **Processing Toolbox** or from the menubar `Vector > Geometry Tools`?

Comment: @Joseph unfortunately they are not lines

Comment: @Noel - Apologies, I was slow at editing the comment :)

Comment: @Joseph thank you that worked. Now I have to sort out the crossing lines. but that is for another day

Comment: yes. I didnt think of searching ring not closed. doh.

Comment: @Noel - Don't worry, I always have trouble finding questions which have (sometimes) weird titles :)